# Having count and group by with django orm

Tags: django

With following models:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(
        unique=True,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )


class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        related_name='reservations',
        verbose_name=_('Utilisateur'),
    )
    day = models.ForeignKey(
        Day,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        related_name='reservations',
    )
```

Trying to do:

> select * from meal_day   left join meal_reservation on meal_day.id =
>   meal_reservation.day_id group by meal_day.id having count (distinct
>   meal_reservation.user_id) <= 1

I'm doing this with:

```
Day.objects \
    .annotate(reserved_users_count=Count('reservations__user_id')) \
    .filter(reserved_users_count__lte=1)
```

But this query produce:

> SELECT "meal_day"."id", "meal_day"."date",
>   COUNT("meal_reservation"."user_id") AS "reserved_users_count" FROM
>   "meal_day" LEFT OUTER JOIN "meal_reservation" ON ("meal_day"."id" =
>   "meal_reservation"."day_id") GROUP BY "meal_day"."id",
>   "meal_day"."date" HAVING COUNT("meal_reservation"."user_id") <= 1
>   ORDER BY "meal_day"."date" ASC

How to produce wanted sql query ?

Comment: You can add distinct on the count: `Count('reservations__user_id', distinct=True)`